# Go modules replace command is not working

Tags: go, go-modules

I have following code structure for go module example (Go 1.14.2 on macOS)

BookingNexus

- go.mod
- main.go
- server.go

I added following dependency for **server.go**

```
package main
import bn "nurture.gitlab.com/Core/Contracs/BookingNexus/Gen/Go"
```

I added following code to go.mod

```
module nurture.gitlab.com/Core/BookingNexus

go 1.14

require (
    nurture.gitlab.com/Core/Contracts latest
)

replace nurture.gitlab.com/Core/Contracts latest => /Users/.../Core/Contracts
```

Since I don't have nurture.gitlab.com right now, so I used `replace` directive, howerver it's still trying to download from nurture.gitlab.com and saying that unable to dail tcp. 
Generating following error if I run `go mod tidy`

```
/Users/.../BookingNexus/go.mod:6: unrecognized import path "nurture.gitlab.com/Core/Contracts": https fetch: Get "https://nurture.gitlab.com/Core/Contracts?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup nurture.gitlab.com: no such host
```

I expect replace command should provide alternative way to get the path, however it's still trying to download from unexistenet path and not considering replace directive at all (I tried including and excluding, got same message both times)

Can somebody help me why is this is the case ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build against your local copy of the package `Contracts`, you need to comment out the remote path:

```
require (
    //
    // comment this out during local development:
    //
    // nurture.gitlab.com/Core/Contracts latest
)

replace nurture.gitlab.com/Core/Contracts => /Users/.../Core/Contracts
```

Once the development is complete and checked into the remote location, then comment out the `replace` and restore the remote-path.

Some things of note from the [golang wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) which apply to your case:

> Note: if the right-hand side of a replace directive is a filesystem path,
>   then the target must have a go.mod file at that location. If the
>   go.mod file is not present, you can create one with go mod init.